# Mule studio install new software offline

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mule, mule-studio

I'm using Mule ESB version 3.8 in eclipse and was handed a project that requires me to use 3.5 in mule studio in order to test it. Unfortunately, I can't just use install new software from the internet because the development I'm doing is on a network that is entirely disconnected from the internet.

Is there any way to install the Mule ESB 3.5 embedded runtime into eclipse if I don't have access to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to do this from anypoint studio but you can try downloading the mule standalone runtime from https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime.

Export your application as a mule deployable archive and run on the standalone runtime from the command line. Hope this helps.

I will update if I know a way to do it from anypoint studio. This may help https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb#starting-and-stopping-mule-via-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can't install new software without downloading it from the internet first. If you are working in an environment without internet, the only way to install a new runtime is as a standalone or .jar file (embedded). Download it from the [website](https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime) on another pc or laptop that is connected to the internet. Put it on a USB stick or other memory device and plug it in your development device and install. I haven't found a way to install the standalone version into Anypoint studio.

The .jar file is only available for the latest version of Mule runtime.

It should also be possible to install new runtimes from within Anypoint Studio (but again not without an internet connection). Go to 'Help' and select 'Install New Software...'. You'll have to enter a url or select a site from the list (the safest thing to do is check [this site](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/studio-update-sites) for urls, because I only encountered errors with the options already listed in Anypoint Studio which might be because of firewall settings). You'll get a list of all the available runtimes and can select and install the one you need.

Again you can't really install a new runtime without an internet connection. I don't know if you're able to switch networks briefly to be able to install the new runtime, ask your project leader if that's an option.